# write a proxy for downloading files from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a server running in a docker container on an AWS vm which exposes UI interface for my users, the users can ask for exporting an existing AWS VMs to a bucket I create on the fly and after that I want to allow them to download the exported file to their local machine (either automatically upon pressing the 'export' button once the export is done or by giving them a link to download this file).

in order to access this file the user must have read permission but I don't know the user-id and I'm sure my clients don't have a user ID or don't know it by heart... the other option is to grant public read access but that's not a good idea...

I know how can I download this file to the server and allow them to download it from there but I was thinking about having some sort of a 'proxy' for this download which will allow the user to download it from my server while the file will not be actually located on it but rather on the bucket, and all I'll have to do is to bind the user's download to a download I'll initiate with S3...

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like authentication issue first
Later some kind of linking identity inside VM (user id which is not set) to aws credentials allowing to download the image

One of ways how I would do it :

```
Create lambda function to copy/download S3

Create html/js GUI in conjunction with Amazon cognito

Create users and group them

Through cognito auth allow download via lambda
```